# How to get a string variable value from "D:\\Directory1\\file1.txt" to @"D:\Directory1\file1.txt"

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting, stringbuilder

I made some C# program which gets the latest created file.
for example is it a `D:\Directory1\file1.txt`   file

And when it gets the file, the address of its file is stored on some variable like this string:
 `"D:\\Directory1\\file1.txt"`
when you watching in debugging you can see this value.

```
   FileInfo f1;                   // this is a latest created file "D:\Directory1\file1.txt"
   string s1 = f1.FullName;       // string value will be "D:\\Directory1\\file1.txt"
   string s2 = SomeFunction(s1);  // in order to get @"D:\Directory1\file1.txt" value
```

if you assign its value to different variable s2, then you will get again the same string value!
So how to assign this value to different variable in order to get @"D:\Directory1\file1.txt" value.
Should I use StringBuilder class?
Should I use String.Format?
Thank you anyway!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking -- can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value you see in the debugger is escaped because it is in C#.

When using the verbatim `@"\"`, it is actually `"\\"`, or as we humans see it on screen `\`.

Don't let your head get messed up by the values you see in the debugger. They are actually okay. Click the magnifier in your Watch and you will see.

Answer (score 2):

The variable is already:

> D:\Directory1\file1.txt

Viewing the string whilst paused in the debugger will escape the backslashes e.g replace `\` with `\\`.

Use the text visualizer or print the value to the console, it should be fine.